# The equivalence between the 0 values of the integral of the absolute value and the squared value of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, how can I prove that:

$\int_{a}^b |f(x)|dx=0 \Leftrightarrow \int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx=0$

Basic as it seems, I am unable to find similar questions since descriptive languages may vary on that question.

Thank you if I can get a proof as basic as possible!

Comment: Are your integrals Riemann integrals or Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: Sorry, they are Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is integrable it is bounded. Suppose $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$. If $\int_a^{b} |f(x)|dx =0$ then $\int_a^{b} |f(x)/M|dx =0$. This implies that $\int_a^{b} |f(x)|^{2}/M^{2}dx =0$ because $|f(x)|^{2}/M^{2} \leq |f(x)/M|$. Hence $\int_a^{b} |f(x)|^{2}dx =0$.

For the  converse the simplest proof I can think of is to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $(\int_a^{b} |f(x)|dx)^{2} \leq  (\int_a^{b} |f(x)|^{2}dx) (b-a)$.

Comment: Thank you! But to think one step further, does it still hold true when $f(x)$ is improperly integrable? The first solution may apply then.

Comment: @XYZ Both parts are true even for  improper Riemann integrals. This can be seen using monotonicity of indefinite integrals for $|f|$ and $|f|^{2}$.

Comment: I am sorry that I meant "may not apply". Let's say $f(x)$ is unbounded on $[a, a+\delta ]$, how do I deal with it?

Comment: @XYZ Apply my arguement to $[a+\delta, b]$ and the let $\delta \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is integrable, the set $S:=\{x\in[a,b]:|f(x)|>0\}$ is a measurable set. Assume that the lebesgue measure of $S$ is not zero, i.e., $|S|>0$. One has
\begin{equation}
0=\int_a^b|f(x)|dx\geq \int_S|f(x)|dx>0
\end{equation}
which is a contradiction. Hence $f=0$ almost everywhere and so
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(x)^2dx=0.
\end{equation}